# A question on Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a complex holomorphic function $f(x+iy)=F(x,y)+iG(x,y)$ where $F,G$ are real-valued. Then how can we express the complex integral $\int f(z)dz$ in terms of the real integrals $\int Fdx,\int Fdy,\int Gdx,\int Gdy$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Complex integral"...as in indefinite integral? If so just evaluate the primitive functions of $\;F,G\;$ ...otherwise, complex integration is usually done as line integrals.

Comment: No, I am sorry for not mentioning it... I meant line integrals over a parametric curve, not an indefinite integral.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can, in the simplest possible way:
$$
f\,dz = (F+iG)(dx+i\,dy) = F\,dx - G\,dy + i(F\,dy + G\,dx).
$$

If $f$ is holomorphic, the path chosen is irrelevant.  So, the integral can be written as:
$$
\int_{z_1}^{z_2}f\,dz = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x,y_1)\,dx + i\int_{x_1}^{x_2} G(x,y_1)\,dx + i\int_{y_1}^{y_2} F(x_2,y)\,dy - \int_{y_1}^{y_2} G(x_2,y)\,dy,
$$

as well as:
$$
\int_{z_1}^{z_2}f\,dz = i\int_{y_1}^{y_2} F(x_1,y)\,dy - \int_{y_1}^{y_2} G(x_1,y)\,dy + \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x,y_2)\,dx + i\int_{x_1}^{x_2} G(x,y_2)\,dx, 
$$

where $z_1=x_1+iy_1$ and $z_2=x_2+iy_2$.

If $f$ is not holomorphic, this does not hold, but in that case the integral would be hard to define.

Comment: why is $dz=dx+idy?$

Comment: $z=x+iy$, and $d$ is linear. If you want, by definition...